# How to group a DataSet on multiple keys?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have a `Dataset` of HashMaps and I have performed a `groupBy` on one of the keys. Now I want to perform one more (or multiple) `groupBy` on the already grouped `DataSet` (i.e. nested or a chained sort of a `groupBy`)

for example, I would like something like this:

```
data.groupBy(_("a")).groupBy(_("b")).reducegroup {....}
```

How will I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `groupBy` is not supported in Flink.
You can however group on composite keys

```
val data: (Int, Int, Long) = ???
val res = data.groupBy(0, 1).reduce(...)
```

In your example you are using KeySelectors which cannot be used in composite keys. Instead, you can define a KeySelector that returns both keys as a `Tuple2`.

```
data.groupBy(d => (d("a"), d("b")) ).reduce(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fabian-hueske! That is exactly what I wanted1